# Fill data frame with specified function data in python

Tags: python, r, dataframe

There is a easy way to generate some vectors and matrix in R

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
```

Is in python some equivalent method to do it?
It is great ease but if there is no counterpart in python just say how should I do this. Probably normal loop using "dataframe"

Comment: Since I don't know much about Python I can't help you but I assume those are easy answers you can find on google by typing : create a matrix python / create a vector in python. Both LyzandeR and boski answers seems to work tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(11)[1:11]
y = x**2
x
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
y
array([  1,   4,   9,  16,  25,  36,  49,  64,  81, 100], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions is usually my way of generating the same. They are simple to use:

```
x = [i for i in range(1, 11)]
y = [z**2 for z in x]

#>>> x
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
#>>> y
#[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is `map`

```
map(lambda y: y **2 , x)
#[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

#### data

```
x = [i for i in range(1, 11)]
```